# Unable to redirect on custom success page after payment in worldpay

Tags: php, payment-gateway, worldpay

I have follow all the below step and setup all the configuration for response redirect in worldpay panel, But still its not redirect on my custom success page.

**I follow the below steps for setup worldpay:**

1. login to Worldpay, open desired installation to edit
2. Tick on "Payment Response enabled?"
3. Provide "Payment Response URL" to the page which will be receiving/processing the POST data from worldpay.
4. Enter same url in "Shopper redirect url"
5. Tick on "Shopper Redirect button enabled"
6. Tick on "Enable the Shopper Response"

I have set the Payment Response URL as : https://my_domain.com/worldpay-response.php and create worldpay-response.php file on my root server path.

But still i am unable to get the $_POST data on worldpay-response.php.

Docs for worldpay payment response : [click here](http://support.worldpay.com/support/kb/bg/paymentresponse/pr0000.html?_ga=2.214856983.1670107561.1531113893-1889345464.1531113893)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spend 2 days by searching for response i find the solution.

Please follow the below steps :

1. Login into [worldpay](https://secure.worldpay.com/sso/public/auth/login.html).
2. Click on **"SETUP"** menu on left side.
3. Click on settings icon of "(Select Junior)" installation for response url setup. For more help see below screenshot

[image]

Set the **payment response URL** and **Shopper Redirect url**.

```
<wpdisplay item="MC_callback">
```

4. Click on **"edit payment pages"** button. For more help see below screenshot.

[image]

5. Select your current installation id and click on edit payments page.

[image]

6. Click on **File Management** left menu and upload both file resultC.html and resultY.html. See screenshots below.

[image]

Content of File **resultC.html**

```
<html>
      <head>
        <title>Thank you for your payment</title>
      </head>
      <WPDISPLAY ITEM="MC_cancelurl" DEFAULT="" PRE="<meta http-equiv='refresh' 
      content='0;url=" POST="' />">
      <b style="text-align:center;">Please wait while you are being redirected.</b>
  </html>
```

Content of file **resultY.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Thank you for your payment</title>
    </head>
    <WPDISPLAY ITEM="MC_returnurl" DEFAULT="" PRE="<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=" POST="' />">
    <b style="text-align:center;">Please wait while you are being redirected.</b>
</html>
```

7. Create your form field on your server for payments from where any user can make payments on wordlpay.

```
    <!-- For live payments url should be https://secure.worldpay.com/wcc/purchase -->

    <form action="https://secure-test.worldpay.com/wcc/purchase" method="POST">

        <!-- This next line contains the testMode parameter - it specifies that the submission is a test submission -->

        <input type="hidden" name="testMode" value="100" > <!-- testmode value sholud be 100 , for live mode 0  -->

        <!-- This next line contains a mandatory parameter. Put your Installation ID inside the quotes after value= -->

        <!-- You will need to get the installation ID from your Worldpay account. Login to your account, click setting and under installations
        you should have an option called select junior and a number, put the number between “” e.g. “123456”-->

        <input type="hidden" name="instId" value="YOUR_INSTALLATION_ID">

        <!-- Another mandatory parameter. Put your own reference identifier for the item purchased inside the quotes after value= -->

        <input type="hidden" name="cartId" value="CART_NAME">

        <!-- Another mandatory parameter. Put the total cost of the item inside the quotes -->

        <!-- Another mandatory parameter. Put the code for the purchase currency inside the quotes after value= like GBP,INR-->

        <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="CURRENCY_CODE">

        <!-- This creates the button. When it is selected in the browser, the form submits the purchase details to us. -->

        <input type="hidden" name="MC_callback" value="YOUR_RESPONSE_URL">

        <input type="hidden" name="MC_returnurl" value="YOUR_RETURN_URL">

        <input type="hidden" name="MC_cancelurl" value="YOUR_CANCEL_URL">

        <input type="text" name="MC_username" value=""  placeholder="Name">

        <input type="text" name="tel" value=""  placeholder="Contact Number">

        <input type="email" name="email" value=""  placeholder="Email Address">

        <input type="text" name="address1" value="" placeholder="House Name/Number">

        <input type="text" name="address2" value=""  placeholder="Street Name">

        <input type="text" name="postcode" value=""  placeholder="Postcode">

        <input type="text" name="amount" value="" required placeholder="amount (&pound;)" id="amount-cs">

        <input type="submit" name="make_wordpay_payment" id="make_wordpay_payment" value="Pay Now">

    </form>
```

I hope this will help you, For more help please follow the below link. 
http://support.worldpay.com/support/kb/bg/customisingadvanced/custa6012.html

Thanks

Comment: tried the same. But stuck in thank you page. Not getting redirected to my site. Do we need to give any redirection code in resultC or resultY.

Comment: Add static url in shopper redirect url. Some time the complete url work like http://example.com/redirecturl.php

Comment: is it possible to give return url in worldpay html form

Comment: No you need to write return url in worldpay dashboard under heading Add static url in shopper redirect url.